# Table info making table overflow outside div

Tags: html, css

```
#container {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    /*bg transparent*/
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    max-width: 960px;
    /*centrat in pagina*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*distanta dintre border si continut*/
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    min-height: 95vh;
    position: relative;
}

#header {
    background-color: #FFA500;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

#menu {

    background-color: #FFD700;
    /*dimensiune*/
    width: 135px;
    /*pozitie*/
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    /*margini fata de elemente*/
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#content {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    /*dimensiune*/
    min-height: 685px;
    width: 740px;
    /*pozitie*/
    position: relative;
    /*margini fata de elemente*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

`Container` has everything. `Header` is inside the `container`, on top. Under it, I have a div called `cont` that has no style associated. Inside it, on the left I have `menu` and `content` on the right. Inside the `content` I have a table that overflows the div. How can I make that table fit inside the div?

Here is an image of my app. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrUzc.png

Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5f9A4/

Comment: post here html code as well

Comment: use {overflow: scroll; } , also please share fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f9A4/ Here is the fiddle. Hopefully it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue came beacuse you have added a long text without any space. Add the following CSS. Hopefully it will resolve the issue.

```
 #content table td
 {
  word-wrap:break-all;
 }
```

I have reproduced(similar to your image) the issue in your fiddle. Check it out [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5f9A4/1/)

After that I have added my above solution to resolve this. Check the [**Updated Solution HERE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5f9A4/2/)

Comment: It this not resolved then share your HTML part for the content area. we can look into that and fix the issue.

Comment: I think there is no problem in your jsfiddle :)

Comment: Yeah because the table is printed through an AJAX script like I showed in the image. That's why I put the image, because I don't know how to put the AJAX code there.

Comment: Did you try my above solution??